# Is there a way to view in real time the query statements the sql server is receiving from my application?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

Is there any tool, or a VS debug option I can use to monitor all the queries my C# application is issuing to the SQL Server? I'd like to know how efficient is my C# code and the ORM at building the queries, like how many SELECTs is it sending at a certain time/situation, and based on that be able to issue raw queries if the ORM is producing complex/multiple queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. [SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173918(SQL.80).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Profiler is good for this, however SQL Express doesn't have this. Just FYI.

You can access this from SQL Server Management Studio (IF you use it)

```
Tools -> SQL Server Profiler
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at the Activity Monitor within Management Studio 2008.  Just right-click the main server node and choose "Activity Monitor".  This link has information about this tool and also opens with the left-hand nav expanded to show several other topics that may be of interest:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175518.aspx